# Adding state variable values in react's input tag

Tags: reactjs, input

```
class Filter extends React.Component {
   constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
       placeholder: true,
       variableValue: '',
      }
   }
  render() {
    return (
     <input placeholder={this.state.placeholder ? "select filter" : this.state.variableValue} />
  )
 }}
```

Now whenever variable input comes in the state from some function defined in another place. I want to change the placeholder value if the variable has some values in the state.

**Is there any way to do this in one line**

Comment: The value of placeholder gets displayed only when the input box is out of focus. You can't have simultaneously value input as well as a placeholder in an input field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are better off with only one state variable and using default value if that variable is not set.

```
class Filter extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            placeholder: null,
        };
    }
    render() {
        return <input placeholder={this.state.placeholder || 'select filter'} />;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not really sure why you are trying to put your value inside a placeholder, but the correct way  to do it would be:

```
class Filter extends React.Component {
   constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
       //placeholder: true,
       variableValue: '',
      }
      this.changeValue=this.changeValue.bind(this)
   }
  changeValue(event){
     this.setState({variableValue:event.target.value})
   }
  render() {
    return (
     <input placeholder="select filter"  value={this.state.variableValue} onChange={changeValue} />
  )
 }}
```

Here we are declaring that the value of the input field will be the state `variableValue` and defining a method that would handle any change in this input field.